# Read embedded file as Uint8Array in WebAssembly instance

Tags: node.js, webassembly, uint8array, assemblyscript

I'm embedding a binary file within a WebAssembly wasm file.

Consider this source:

embed.ts (gets built to embed.wasm using AssemblyScript):

```
export const text: u8[] = [83,65,77,80,76,69,10]; // The text "SAMPLE" in UTF-8 encoding

export const textLength: i32 = text.length;
```

worker.js:

```
const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(/* read embed.wasm */).exports;
instance.textLength // prints 7, correct
instance.text // prints, 10232 of type number, ?!?!?
```

How can I read out this byte array to enable reconstruction of the embedded file? I need to recreate the Uint8Array so in worker.js I can save the file or stream it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAssembly in current stage can pass only numbers between wasm module and javascript host, so `instance.text` is just number (pointer) or offset in linear memory. In order to read real data from this memory you could use `__getUint8Array` or `__getArray` from [loader](https://docs.assemblyscript.org/basics/loader). Also [useful info](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/tree/master/lib/loader)

Comment: Bingo thanks @MaxGraey for pointing me in the direction, I used the loaded and I extracted the file perfectly.